# - Automate testing web. - Automate web tasks - obtaining data ( Obtener Datos de Una Pagina Web)

Tags: python, request, beautifulsoup

I need a little help. I'm doing a small project,i wonder if can do a similar code, but more independent,because selenium ,required an "webdriver- firefox" and having to run the "jar selenium-server" ,the important thing is to obtain data of time buses, of the page 'http://web.smsbus.cl/web/', maybe there is an easier way, i want to run this script in a mobil and this are a problem running firefox each time that run the script

Code --

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

## servidor java consola-> java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar

driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', {'browserName': 'firefox'})
try:
    #iniciamos el buscador
    driver.get('http://web.smsbus.cl/web/')
    #Buscar el marco o frame correcto
    driver.switch_to_frame('busqueda')


    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="lista_servicio"]/option[contains(text(),"E04")]').click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="lista_hacia"]/option[contains(text(),"AV. LA FLORIDA")]').click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="lista_paradero"]/option[contains(text(),"ALC.CARLOS VALDOVINOS ESQ. / M.TORO Y ZAMBRANO")]').click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="botones_busqueda"]/a[1]').click()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)

    tiempo_de_llegada=soup.find(id="proximo_tiempo_respuesta")
    distancia =soup.find(id="proximo_distancia_respuesta")
    patente =soup.find(id="proximo_bus_respuesta")

    print tiempo_de_llegada,distancia,patente
    #print soup.find(id="respuesta_error").text
    print 
    print 'Todo ok c:'
    print
finally:
    driver.close()
```

when the buses are in transit , works xD, this super beta, only I jump I doubt if it can be most effec. thx for all

Comment: Your text needs editing but I do not understand enough to do so.  What is 'esque', for instance?

Comment: sorry all "esque" is deleted, Thanks for warning me, I need to get the data from the times of the buses of this page 'http://web.smsbus.cl/web/', without WebDriver "Firefox" and selenium-server, because are a problem if i want make a program for mobil , the mobil will be not running firefox each time that run the script